# PREGUNTA SOBRE SELECT * FROM

Tags: php, mysql

buen dia, mi pregunta es la siguiente, estoy experimentando con base de datos, y tengo solo 1 registro en la base de datos y lo muestro mediante lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla
```

muy bien, siguiendo esto me muestra solo el registro que tengo, como le hago para repetir ese mismo registro digamos unas 5 veces?.. es decir duplicar 5 veces en ves de que me muestre solo 1 que es por default.. gracias

Comment: Ya has probado a insertar 5 registros?

Comment: Es mejor que agregues mas datos a tu tabla, consulta las opciones que dispones con SQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: creo que es lo mejor @IvanBotero

Comment: Hola Rick , como curiosidad, con que objetivo requieres repetir la información? Si tienes un registro y deseas imprimir 5 veces ese registro simplemente llama SELECT * FROM tabla en 5 ocasiones, sin embargo esto no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 2):

No entendí muy bien tu pregunta, pero por lo menos en Postgres yo lo haría así:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM
    (
         SELECT * FROM tabla
    )a
CROSS JOIN

    (   
        SELECT generate_series(1, 3)
    )b;
```

De todas maneras, creo que lo que quieres hacer pasa mas por PHP que por SQL.

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes imprimir el el resultado del query en 5 ocasiones, sin embargo como te comentaba no tiene sentido mostrar la información nuevamente, ya que únicamente tienes un registro en la tabla.

```
DECLARE @counter INT;
SET @counter = 0;

WHILE @counter < 5
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM tabla
   SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END;
```

esto es similar a :

```
 SELECT * FROM tabla
 SELECT * FROM tabla
 SELECT * FROM tabla
 SELECT * FROM tabla
 SELECT * FROM tabla
```

La pregunta sería, cual es el objetivo de esto.

Comment: quiero hacer un stock de 5 a 10 imagenes con informacion, pero quiero ejemplificar con el mismo y unico registro y ver como se acomodan en la web de ejempo, por que no tengo 5 ó 10 "productos que mostrar aun" espero haberme explicado

Answer (score -1):

eso lo puedes hacer mmediante un bucle for y una funcion de php

```
function imagenes(){
//hacer la consulta a  la base de datos sacando la ruta y la informacion del sql
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){// el <= que 5 se pone para que repita ese bucle 5 beces 
    echo "inserta aqui el img con todo y saca la informacion de la base de datos previamente hecho antes del bucle for ";
}
// si esto lo llamas desde un index.php con el include de la pagina donde tegas la funcion luego se haria asi
```

}

Comment: Y aquí como es que se ve el uso de la consulta?

Comment: @element el  uso de la consulta lo tiene que poner el con las variables a las que haya asignado en la consulta de php y mysql  te refieres a que edite para ver donde quedarian las variables por que solo hay que poner variables en donde quieras que aparezca lo que has consultado

Comment: La idea es dar una respuesta completa

Comment: @element el a pedido que se repita 5 veces para probar en una web  yo le he dado la solucion del for la respuesta esta completa asumo que el sabe hacer la consulta a la base por que de eso no ha hablado simple tu sabes dar una respuesta?

Comment: Hay un error en el código: ese bucle se repite 6 veces (0-5 incluidos los dos)

Comment: @alva cierto es lo corrijo